# Download file based on user metadata fields from S3 bucket in java

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-s3

I need to upload/download file in s3 bucket with user metadata organisationID, OrganisationType, fileType. Filename will be same(file.pdf, file.xls) but it contents will be differ based on organisationID, OrganisationType, fileType

if organisationID =1, OrganisationType=A, fileType = P then i need to download file.pdf

If organisationID =1, OrganisationType=A, fileType = X then i need to download file.xls.
I have below dbouts, How to have same keyname in bucket as filename is same in different scenarios
how to download file based on userMeta files without key

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to mimic a hierarchical layout. You could make the key name for oraganizationID=1, OrganizationType=A fileType=P as 1/A/P/file.pdf. Similarly you could make the key name for organisationID=1, OrganisationType=A, fileType=X as 1/A/X/file.xls. Another way is to just embed the metadata in the key name without mimicking a directory structure like 1_A_P_file.pdf. Given the metadata and known file naming logic you can recreate the key name and retrieve the appropriate file. Strip away the metadata in the file name prior to returning the file to the end user.